# how to write a shell script to run multiple commands

Tags: linux, shell

I want to run two commands

`ssh -f mike@c15-0330-01.com 'nohup Rscript L_1.R > L_1_sh.txt'`

and

`ssh -f mike@c15-0330-02.com 'nohup Rscript L_2.R > L_2_sh.txt'`

I write a shell script `test_1.sh`as following:

`ssh -f mike@c15-0330-01.com 'nohup Rscript L_1.R > L_1_sh.txt' ;
 ssh -f mike@c15-0330-02.com 'nohup Rscript L_2.R > L_2_sh.txt'`

But it always run the first command. And it does not run the second command. The terminal shows

> : command not found:

Comment: How did you get to know? Did you check `ps -aux`?

Comment: I check the computer c15-0330-02.com and use `top`.

Comment: Does the second command work by itself from the command line?

Comment: Are concurrent logins for that account allowed? Are concurrent runs of `Rscript` allowed? Do you get any errors from the script/ssh commands? Does adding `wait` after the second `ssh` "fix" things?

Comment: I use `./test_1.sh`. Then, I get `: command not found:` in the terminal.

Comment: The error message is not coming from any of the two ssh commands, but from some other part of "test_1.sh"

Comment: @SamVarshavchik. I only put two commands in `test_1.sh`.

Comment: `set -x` is your friend for debugging this kind of thing. I'd be unsurprised if there were hidden characters at play; `set -x` (or `bash -x yourscript`) will show them.

Comment: Also: **PLEASE, PLEASE** don't use backticks for quoting full lines of code on StackOverflow, especially in bash, where they're semantically meaningful! If you select your code and click the `{}` button in the editor, it'll indent your selection with four spaces, which marks that content as code; you can also just type four spaces at the beginning of each line yourself. Then we don't have to wonder if you're putting unnecessary literal backticks in your command (a mistake some people make), or just don't know how to use StackOverflow code formatting correctly.

Comment: ...if you _were_ using literal backticks, that could actually explain your bug, if the remote command returned a nonprintable character in its stdout that were then being reported as not-found locally.

Comment: Much more likely, of course, is just that your file has DOS newlines rather than being a UNIX text file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Thanks, Now it works. But I still get message `:command not found`

Comment: @Ben, if you're running `bash -x yourscript`, you should have more information printed to stderr than just that error. That information is important. (You might also consider putting `set -x;` at the front of each command line passed to ssh).

Answer (score 1):

ssh -f mike@c15-0330-01.com 'nohup Rscript L_1.R > L_1_sh.txt' ;
 ssh -f mike@c15-0330-02.com 'nohup Rscript L_2.R > L_2_sh.txt'

The error message is correct  becaue there is no program named 'nohup -f mike...' on the destination system.

Run the test command:

ssh mike@c15-0330-01.com echo 1 2 3

The [command] executed by ssh(1) can consist of multiple words, just not filename redirection; do that inside your script.